# How to remove null value from NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, nsurl

Please advice me for what to do remove the key also from url if that particular key has not any value available.

For ex.

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=18&apiKey=rcnge5sr7v4yebfmr2p44gpq&cid=451493&city=London&CurrencyCode=USD&cyCode=US&numberOfResults=50&numberOfAdults=1&numberOfChildren=0&searchRadius=50&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED&arrivalDate=01/24/2014&departureDate=01/25/2014&room1=1&room2=0&room3=0&room4=0&propertyCategory=&amenities=&minStarRating=&maxStarRating=&minRate=&maxRate=
```

I have this url I want to remove the value with keys if there isn't any value.

I want to convert this url like following

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=18&apiKey=rcnge5sr7v4yebfmr2p44gpq&cid=451493&city=London&CurrencyCode=USD&cyCode=US&numberOfResults=50&numberOfAdults=1&numberOfChildren=0&searchRadius=50&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED&arrivalDate=01/24/2014&departureDate=01/25/2014&room1=1
```

because the rest parameter are 0 or blank.

What is a best practice to achieve this.
Either I want to apply condition one by one or is there any other smart approach.

Comment: If a key has no value then you should not add it to the URL query string, instead of removing it later ...

Comment: When you are constructing the URL, just don't add stuff that are empty/null.

Comment: check my answer given below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take one method and pass the values and check weather the value is there or not if there then Append it otherwise leave like that

```
 for (NSString *key in parametersDictKeyValues) {
       [self addArgument:key argumentValue:[parametersDict objectForKey:key]];
}
-(void)addArgument:(NSString *)key argumentValue:(id)value {
    if(key != nil && value != nil) {
        baseUrlWithParameters = [baseUrlWithParameters stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@=%@&",key,value];
    }
}
```

> and finally remove the last & symbol from baseUrlWithParameters

Comment: So how doesn't he get the key/value pairs in the first place?

Comment: Thanks Sunny. Actually this was not my answer but your answer can might be useful in future. Take +1 also for this.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I post my query, I got an idea to achieve this.

I used

> stringByAppendingString

to include only those parameter who are not null

if any value is not available then the string would not append it.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Seriously?  That is your solution?